# FlinkSQL not filtering Float column with an equality predicate

Tags: floating-point, apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm trying to use FlinkSQL to filter data with an equality predicate on Float type Column. The code is as follows:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val source = env.fromElements(
      (1.0f, 11.0f, 12.0f),
      (2.0f, 21.0f, 22.0f),
      (3.0f, 31.0f, 32.0f),
      (4.0f, 41.0f, 42.0f),
      (5.0f, 51.0f, 52.0f)
    )
    val settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance()
        .inStreamingMode()
        .useBlinkPlanner()
        .build()
    val tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, settings)
    tEnv.createTemporaryView("myTable", source, $("id"), $("f1"), $("f2"))
    val query =
      """
        |select * from myTable where id in (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
        |""".stripMargin
    tEnv.executeSql(query).print()
```

The execution throws an exception, as follows：

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class org.apache.calcite.sql.type.SqlTypeName: FLOAT
    at org.apache.calcite.util.Util.needToImplement(Util.java:1075)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.appendAsJava(RexLiteral.java:703)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.toJavaString(RexLiteral.java:408)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.computeDigest(RexLiteral.java:276)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.<init>(RexLiteral.java:223)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.toLiteral(RexLiteral.java:737)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.lambda$printSarg$4(RexLiteral.java:710)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.RangeSets$Printer.singleton(RangeSets.java:397)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.RangeSets.forEach(RangeSets.java:237)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.Sarg.lambda$printTo$0(Sarg.java:110)
    at org.apache.calcite.linq4j.Ord.forEach(Ord.java:157)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.Sarg.printTo(Sarg.java:106)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.printSarg(RexLiteral.java:709)
    at org.apache.calcite.rex.RexLiteral.lambda$appendAsJava$1(RexLiteral.java:652)
    at org.apache.calcite.util.Util.asStringBuilder(Util.java:2502)
```

Because my source or sink may be of Float type, I hope to use Float type directly to process。

My Flink version is flink-1.12.0

This has bothered me for a long time, and I hope to get help. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure this is the reason _why_ Calcite is refusing to parse that SQL expression, but testing floating point numbers equality is considered unreliable in any computer system and our code should not rely on it. Floats are an  _approximate_ representation of real numbers and exact reasoning based on them is leading to many corner case bugs. Again, I'm not convinced that is the root cause of this exact issue, but I would recommend not to rely on such behavior even if it were supported. Maybe try to round/multiply the numbers in some way and then rely on integer or string comparison instead?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am developing a Flink connector based on our database. I cannot guarantee whether users will use Float or not. I see Spark, Hive can also support filtering based on Float type fields, while Spark and Hive SQL is also parsed based on Calcite, as is Flink, so I think it would be better if Flink can also support it.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20942

Comment: @Svend: Floating-point numbers do not approximate real numbers. Per the IEEE 754 standard, each floating-point number **is** one real number, exactly. Floating-point **operations** approximate real-number arithmetic operations. This difference is crucial for understanding, designing, and proving floating-point algorithms.

Comment: Hi Eric. Yes, you are right, I was too quick conflating the two since floating-point values _typically_ result from math operations, although that's a different point indeed. In the context of the question though, that concept becomes blurry since the `source` is meant to read a float from an external storage and compare it with a Java float. Depending on how aligned that storage and Java are regarding float representations, and how choice of storage evolve over time, the stability of equality predicate behavior seems hard to rely on to me. Probably I'm starting to be pedantic here, sorry :)

Comment: Thank you for your discussion. I also learned a lot from your discussion. Because Flink is developed in java+scala, and our database is also developed in java, so in my case, can flink support the implementation of the correct float type Filter?